# Variables at file scope are not getting initialized using other variable

Tags: c

Can someone please explain why this underlying code is looking for a **constant** value for initialization? Doing the same thing within a function doesn't cause any trouble (even if the other variable - b in this case - is a constant).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a=9;
int b=a;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

A similar question has been just asked few moments ago (don't know how) but the answer is just because the design specifications of the language says so (which is not helpful)- can anyone explain the purpose it serves that way?

Comment: `i` has not yet been defined, but even if is has, the language rules say the value used must be a constant, so it's no use even to define `const int i`.

Comment: Where is 'i' declared?

Comment: “Because the language says so” is the only valid answer.

Comment: Please see [ISO/IEC 9899:201x](www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) Sorry I can't see why the link isn't working.

Comment: @WeatherVane Missing `http://`.

Comment: @dbash: If “Because the language says so” is the only valid answer, why does the [C Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) exist?

Comment: Why the down votes? It is a properly posed question and has an answer.

Comment: URL for (draft) C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) is [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It is a question for which the only answer is a variant on "because the language standard say so".  There really isn't a good way to explain why the language doesn't do so other than "the designer(s) didn't mae it do so" (with a sub-text of "it is certainly simpler to implement the language as it is than as you'd like it to be").

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The C language is not arbitrary, and it was not found carved into a rock. It evolved and was designed, comments were submitted to the committees, and they used reasoning and discussion to recommend a standard. Of course there are reasons the standard says various things.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The thing which I understood is that variables `a`&`b` can be accessed from other translational units and there is no guarantee that `b` will be accessed after a hence the compiler throws an error, but even if I make `b` as `static` it doesn't help - throws same error. I mean with static keyword `b`'s linkage should've become internal. The global variables should be initialized serially top-to bottom in a single translational unit.

Comment: The C language simply doesn't allow initialization of variables with [static storage duration](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4) from a non-constant, and `b` is not a constant (and wouldn't be even if qualified by `const`).  It would be possible to design a language such that this wasn't a restriction — C++ is such a language (the code compiles in C++).  However, that language isn't C as currently defined.

Answer (score 3):

The `a` and `b` objects you show have static storage duration, meaning they exist during the entire execution of the program. The 2011 version of the C standard (draft N1570), clause 6.7.9, paragraph 4, says “All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.”

C does not have any provisions for calculating the initial values of static objects. Their values need to be determined at compile time or be *relocatable addresses* that can be calculated by the linker or loader. Relocatable address are calculated as simple expressions  that are functions of where the portions of a program are loaded in memory.

Objects declared inside functions (technically, inside blocks, which are inside function definitions) without `extern` or `static` have automatic storage duration. The C standard allows these to be be initialized with expressions that are computed at run time. It is relatively easy for compilers to implement this, because they simply put code to calculate the values at the start of the function.

Theoretically, the C standard could allow you to initialize static objects with values calculated at run-time, and implementations could implement this by including code that executes before `main`. Other programming languages have such features. However, it introduces complications. For example, if you write `extern int b; int a = 3*b;` in one source file and `extern int a; int b = a+4;` in another, which one should get executed first? How do you write language rules to prohibit this? There may be solutions to this and other problems, but C began when language development was still young, and it avoids complications like this.

Comment: The thing which I understood is that variables a&b can be accessed from other translational units and there is no guarantee that `b` will be accessed after `a` hence the compiler throws an error, but even if I make `b` as `static` it doesn't help - throws same error. I mean with `static` keyword `b`'s linkage should've become internal. The global variables should be initialized serially top - to bottom in a single translational unit.